# What does web3.eth.call(tx) return for a contract creation?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

When using `web3.eth.call(tx)` for a method call, the return value is a byte string that can be decoded by using `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(abi.outputs, bytestring)`. But for a contract creation transaction, we don't have `abi.outputs`.

Running some test code I can see that web3 is returning some bytestring:

The transaction:

```
{ from: '0x0838ab6597248e7fb1c11e582eaf88550cce5fb6',
        to: undefined,
        data: '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',
        value: '0x0',
        gas: '0x33274' }
```

The returned bytestring:

```
'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'
```

What information is encoded in this bytestring? And can I recover the to-be-deployed contract address?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I would guess it's returning the resulting byte code (the code that would reside at the new address). If you just want to know the address in advance before deploying the contract, you can just compute it yourself from the hash of the sender's address and nonce.

Comment: Thanks! That's a reasonable guess, I'll check if it is the case.
Can you give a code example of computing the contract's address ahead of time (using web3 1.0)?

Comment: I'm not sure that can easily be done with just web3.js. But it's (pseudocode) `keccak256(rlp([senderAddress, nonce]))`. The last 20 bytes of that is the address.

Comment: Using the `rlp` and `keccak` node modules, I think this works: `keccak('keccak256').update(rlp.encode([sender, nonce])).digest('hex').substring(24);`

Comment: is `nonce` the result of `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)`? or `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender) + 1`

Comment: No  `+ 1` needed. (The first nonce should be 0, so you want to use 0 when the transaction count is 0.)

Comment: I've confirmed that it's indeed the deployed bytecode, and that your code works. Although I would also wrap it with `web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(address)`.

Answer (score 1):

The returned bytestring is the `deployedBytecode` of the contract, i.e. it's what is returned by `web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress)`.

To get the to-be-deployed contract address use the following code:

```
const rlp = require('rlp');
const keccak = require('keccak');

const sender = '0x123...' // the address that sends the contract creation tx
const nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(sender)
const contractAddress = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(keccak('keccak256').update(rlp.encode([sender, nonce])).digest('hex').substring(24))
```